# Rails 4 - ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

I have read other issues about it, but still I can't point what is causing the error. I have defined the strong parameters of Rails 4, but it keeps showing the error:

> ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError in MessagesController#create

My view is this:

```
<%= form_for(@message) do |f| %>
    <div class="form-group field">
  <%= f.label :phrase %>
  <br/>
  <%= f.text_field :phrase,  autofocus: true, class: 'form-control' %>
</div>
<div class="form-group field">
  <%= f.label :date %>
  <br/>
  <%= f.date_field :date, class: 'form-control' %>
</div>
<div class="actions text-center">
  <%= f.submit "Submit", class: 'btn btn-default' %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

My controller:

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController

def today
    @dates = Message.all()
end

def history
    @messages = Message.history_checker
end

def new
    @message = Message.new
end

def create
    @message = Message.new(params[:message])
    if @message.save
        flash[:notice] = "OK"
        redirect_to root_path
    else
        render :action => 'new'
    end
end

private

def message_params
  params.require(:message).permit(:phrase,:date)
end 
end
```

The error points to line 15 of controller `@message = Message.new(params[:message])`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use `message_params` instead of `params[:message]`:

```
@message = Message.new(message_params)
```

Comment: It works now thanks!, but can I ask what is exactly the difference between message_params and params[:message]? I'm a little puzzled because I used params[:object] in another project and it worked without problems.

Comment: What is the Rails version of this and the other projet?

Comment: @Vicvans read up on Strong Parameters http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters

Comment: @oscar Both are on Rails 4.1